# How to set Run Configuration's environment region in Java Spring, STS?

Tags: java, spring, environment, region

I am trying to run a Java Spring project in STS locally rather than on the server. This project takes on a REGION which I am trying to set to DEV, and I'd like to set it in Run Configurations so that I don't get this: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem with required environment variable REGION!"

Any help, possibly with screenshots or something would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: STS in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options here:

1. Via menu <kbd>Run</kbd> <kbd>Run Configurations</kbd> <kbd>Arguments (second tab)</kbd>
   add VM arguments `-DREGION=DEV`
2. Via menu <kbd>Run</kbd> <kbd>Run Configurations</kbd> <kbd>Environment (tab six)</kbd>
   <kbd>Add...</kbd> arguments `REGION` =  `DEV`

Note: if you use both options, then VM arguments `-DREGION=DEV` will win

VM arguments can be used to launch your app via CLI:

`java -DREGION=DEV -jar your_nice_app.jar`

Comment: thanks. This did work.